# How can I determine the type of internet connetion with a Batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a way to determine whether my internet connection is based on wifi, ethernet, or cellular with a Batch script. My end goal is to have a script run on startup that determines what the connection type is, and as long as it *isn't cellular*, start a certain application. How can I determine the type of internet connection?

Thanks for any help or ideas!

(I'm a relative newbie at batch, so I would really appreciate all the detail you could give me)

Comment: Firstly, remember your connection type could change at any time. Secondly, try connecting via wifi and checking your IP address with `ipconfig` then connect via cellular and check your IP address again. You will likely find that they start differently.

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I spent about an hour searching Google and SO. As I mentioned, I'm a newbie. I'm not looking for someone to write code for me, I'm looking for someone to point me in the right direction, because I don't even know where to start.

Comment: I think Mark was kinda saying this but if you go into the `ipconfig` command, you should see `....media disconnected` under cellular if it is connected to something else. I think it is possible to use the find command to see if that exists in a file after doing something like `ipconfig>test.txt` and `find Cellular: *media disconnected` or something like that.

Comment: what if the computer connects to internet through both wifi and ethernet, or multiple ethernet adapters at once?

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic nic where "NetEnabled=TRUE" get description |find "Mobile Broadband" >nul && (
  echo Mobile connection active
) || (
  echo Mobile connection inactive
)
```

get all network adapters that are connected and look, if `Mobile Broadband" is among them. Execute commands if yes (`&&`) and other commands, if not (`||`)

You might need to adapt the string `Mobile Broadband` to your actual hardware.

Note: just because it's activ, it doesn't mean, your traffic runs through it; there might be more than one activ adapter.